# Deconvolution of Image3D object using ImageDeconvolve

Tags: image-processing, bugs, version-9, filtering, image3d

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.0**

---

I am trying to get the [ImageDeconvolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageDeconvolve.html) function to work with `Image3D` objects. In the documentation of `ImageDeconvolve` it says:

> [ImageDeconvolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageDeconvolve.html) works with [Image3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Image3D.html) objects.

But I can't get the function to work. I tried the following:

```
kernel = GaussianMatrix[{{7, 7, 7}, 2}];
Image3D@kernel // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

```
img3d = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"]
```

[image]

```
ImageDeconvolve[img3d, GaussianMatrix[{{1, 1, 1}, 1}], 
 Method -> {"RichardsonLucy", "Preconditioned" -> True}, 
 MaxIterations -> 16]
```

[image]

Deconvolution seems to be applied only to the first plane. Is `ImageDeconvolve` just not working for `Image3D` or am I doing something wrong here? I also tried different algorithms, kernels and other options without success.

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour you see, with 9.0.1.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention: I am also working on version 9.0.1.

Comment: I would contact support about it.  If they confirm it's a bug, you can come back and note it in an answer (so the question doesn't stay unresolved).

Comment: I reported it as a possible bug/missing feature to Wolfram.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm a consultant at Wolfram Research. It is a bug which will be fixed in Mathematica 10. 
Here is a workaround for Mathematica 9.0.1:

```
Image3D[ListDeconvolve[GaussianMatrix[{{1, 1, 1}, 1}], ImageData[img3d], 
  Method -> {"RichardsonLucy", "Preconditioned" -> True}, MaxIterations -> 16]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Looking forward to Mathematica version 10.